# How to show same progress bar for 3 audio file in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm new to iPhone programming.I have 3 audio files,playing one by one but I want to show progress bar continuously.
For Example 1st audio duration is 5sec,2nd is 6sec,3rd is 10 sec.Here total duration is 21 this one is fine.Using below code total duration progress bar is fine while playing 1st audio.while playing 2nd audio its again its showing progress bar from starting.But I want to continue 1st audio,2nd audio,3rd audio same progress bar.
Please help me to solve this.

```
self.newtimerr1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar1:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)updateProgressBar:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSTimeInterval playTime = [self.audioPlayer currentTime];
    NSTimeInterval duration = 21;
    float progress = playTime/duration;
    [self.progressView1 setProgress:progress];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
   float count;
}
```

In .m file

```
count = 0.0;
self.newtimerr1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar1:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)updateProgressBar1:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    count += 0.1;
    NSTimeInterval duration = 21;
    float progress = count/duration;
    [self.progressView1 setProgress:progress];

    if (!self.audioPlayer.playing) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: No,no.. its working F9.I have some other issues is der.u have any idea about it a?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218342/how-to-stop-audio-after-finishing-loop-in-ios

Answer (score 2):

In addition to this keep the track of audio file too. Keep the duration of audio files in an array and keep another variable, something like audioIndex.
In .h,

```
NSArray *durationArray;
int audioIndex;
```

In your implementation,

```
durationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"5.0", @"6.0", @"10.0", nil];
```

Update audio index accordingly. Then update your method like,

```
- (void)updateProgressBar:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  NSTimeInterval playTime = 0;

 for(int i = 0; i < audioIndex; i++)
 {
   playTime += [[durationArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
 }

  playTime += [self.audioPlayer currentTime];
  NSTimeInterval duration = 21;
  float progress = playTime/duration;
  [self.progressView1 setProgress:progress];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving replay.little bit confusing about durationArray and audio index ?

Comment: Keep the durations in durationArray and current playing audio index as audioIndex. If 2nd audio is playing now, audioIndex is 1 and [durationArray objectAtIndex:1] is 6sec.

Comment: Yaa its working F9.I have some other issues is der.u have any idea about it a?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218342/how-to-stop-audio-after-finishing-loop-in-ios

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42020/discussion-between-aslam-and-anusha)

Answer (score 0):

get the all 3 file total duration like

```
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:audioFileURL options:nil];
CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
float audioDurationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration);
```

get a class variable of NSTimeInterval like totalPlayedTime to tack total spend time then simply

do this

```
float progress = playTime/duration;
[self.progressView1 setProgress:progress];
```

this will do for you i hope