# How to stop audio after finishing loop in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm new to iPhone programming. Using below code I'm displaying image with audio. Images and audio I have stored in array.After audio completed in `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` method I'm using this code I'm displaying next image with audio.
   Every thing is work fine. But problem is after audio and images are finish, again its coming from starting. May be some problem in below code can any one correct it plz..

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
  for (NSString* path in array000)
    {
        [blaukypath2 addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
        NSLog(@"%@",path);
    }
    currentImage++;
    NSError *error;
    if (currentImage >= blaukypath2.count) currentImage = 0;
    UIImage *blaukyyimag = [blaukypath2 objectAtIndex:currentImage];
    [img10 setImage:blaukyyimag];
    NSLog(@"%icurrentImage++ DIDF",currentImage);
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[audiopath2 objectAtIndex:currentImage] error:&error] ;
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: How is `currentImage` declared?  Is `blaukypath2` allocated?

Comment: Why you are using `currentImage = 0;` in the code?

Comment: i Want to display and play audio one after another

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to repeat the image and audio than remove this line in the code..

```
if (currentImage >= blaukypath2.count) currentImage = 0;
```

Because this line will make your currentImage 0. So the loop will start again.

**UPDATE**
Do it like this

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
  for (NSString* path in array000)
    {
        [blaukypath2 addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
        NSLog(@"%@",path);
    }
    if (currentImage < blaukypath2.count)
    {
       currentImage++;
       NSError *error;
       UIImage *blaukyyimag = [blaukypath2 objectAtIndex:currentImage];
       [img10 setImage:blaukyyimag];
       NSLog(@"%icurrentImage++ DIDF",currentImage);
       audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[audiopath2 objectAtIndex:currentImage] error:&error] ;
       audioPlayer.delegate = self;
       [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
       [audioPlayer play];
    }
}
```

Comment: hey first two images working but after that its crashing.it showing error like this *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31aa22a3 0x3974797f 0x319edb75 0xa5557 0x323b90f5 0x31a77683 0x31a76ee9 0x31a75cb7 0x319e8ebd 0x319e8d49 0x355ac2eb 0x338fe301 0x1ae6d 0x39b7eb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: That means `currentImage` is exceeding the value of `blaukypath2.count`. You have to limit it.

Comment: What is the value of blaukypath2.count and audiopath2.count?

Comment: I think this array does not have same value

Answer (score 0):

befor plying next audio, stop previous one.

```
[audioPlayer stop];
```

Hopes it work for you.

Comment: Isn't that what the delegate method `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` implies anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Make a instance variable int arrayIndex; initialize with = 0

```
 - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    if([array000 count] > arrayIndex) {

      NSString* path = [arrayIndex objectAtIndex:arrayIndex];

      [blaukypath2 addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
      NSLog(@"%@",path);

      currentImage++;
     NSError *error;
     if (currentImage >= blaukypath2.count) currentImage = 0;
     UIImage *blaukyyimag = [blaukypath2 objectAtIndex:currentImage];
     [img10 setImage:blaukyyimag];
     NSLog(@"%icurrentImage++ DIDF",currentImage);
     audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[audiopath2      objectAtIndex:currentImage] error:&error] ;
     audioPlayer.delegate = self;
     [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
     [audioPlayer play];

   }

    arrayIndex++;
} else {
 [audioPlayer stop];
}
```

try this approach and let me know if it work

Comment: Why a *class* variable?

Comment: else you can not track the array index, local will reset every time

Comment: But why *class* variable instead of *instance* variable?

Comment: Sorry I was saying the instance variable! Thanks for reminding